# On production build getting ' Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(a)[t]:'....

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular6

Angular 6 App works fine on ng build.

But on ng build --prod app UI gets loaded but on login i ll get coorect data from server, after that i am navigating to dashboard page through the code `this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);` there i am getting error as follows

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(a)[t]: StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[t]: NullInjectorError: No provider for t! Error: StaticInjectorError(a)[t]: StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[t]: NullInjectorError: No provider for t! at t.get (main.aa8ef128615c160bd861.js:1) at main.aa8ef128615c160bd861.js:1 at t (main.aa8ef128615c160bd861.js:1) at t.get (main.aa8ef128615c160bd861.js:1) at main.aa8ef128615c160bd861.js:1 at t (main.aa8ef128615c160bd861.js:1) at t.get (main.aa8ef128615c160bd861.js:1) at Da (main.aa8ef128615c160bd861.js:1) at t.get (main.aa8ef128615c160bd861.js:1) at t.getToken (main.aa8ef128615c160bd861.js:1) at t.get (main.aa8ef128615c160bd861.js:1) at main.aa8ef128615c160bd861.js:1 at t (main.aa8ef128615c160bd861.js:1) at t.get (main.aa8ef128615c160bd861.js:1) at main.aa8ef128615c160bd861.js:1 at t (main.aa8ef128615c160bd861.js:1) at t.get (main.aa8ef128615c160bd861.js:1) at Da (main.aa8ef128615c160bd861.js:1) at t.get (main.aa8ef128615c160bd861.js:1) at t.getToken (main.aa8ef128615c160bd861.js:1) at j (polyfills.9a5f6d04e0781d28c53e.js:1) at j (polyfills.9a5f6d04e0781d28c53e.js:1) at polyfills.9a5f6d04e0781d28c53e.js:1 at e.invokeTask (polyfills.9a5f6d04e0781d28c53e.js:1) at Object.onInvokeTask (main.aa8ef128615c160bd861.js:1) at e.invokeTask (polyfills.9a5f6d04e0781d28c53e.js:1) at t.runTask (polyfills.9a5f6d04e0781d28c53e.js:1) at d (polyfills.9a5f6d04e0781d28c53e.js:1) at t.invokeTask [as invoke] (polyfills.9a5f6d04e0781d28c53e.js:1) at _ (polyfills.9a5f6d04e0781d28c53e.js:1)

My App.module.ts looks like,

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { MaterialModule } from './angular-material/material.module';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing-module';
import { FiltersComponent } from './filters/filters.component';
import { SearchComponent } from './search/search.component';
import { ChartComponent } from './chart/chart.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { KeysPipe } from './shared/pipes/keys.pipe';
import { PdfViewerModule } from 'ng2-pdf-viewer';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    FiltersComponent,
    SearchComponent,
    ChartComponent,
    KeysPipe,
    AboutComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    ChartsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    PdfViewerModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

App environment is:-

```
    Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 10.2.1
OS: linux x64
Angular: 6.0.4
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

- 0.6.8, .6.8, .6.8, .6.8, -0.6.8, @angular/cdk -6.2.1, @angular/cli -6.0.8, @angular/material - 6.2.1, - 6.0.8, .6.8, - 0.6.8 , rxjs-6.2.1, typescript -2.7.2, webpack -4.8.3
```

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem with a missing provider in one of my components, to easier debug this I suggest this:

> Enable the detailed output by going into angular.json file and editing the production: object so that: "aot": true , "optimization": false, "buildOptimizer": false.

This removes the uglification during build so the error log contains the missing module names

Answer (score 3):

The problem is,

I was using the CanActivateChild authgaurd service in app-routing.module.ts file,
This service should have been provided in app.module.ts providers array, i missed it.

provided that service in providers array in app module file then worked fine.

But In dev(ng build) build it was not throwing me any error.

Comment: For me, it was the CdkConnectedOverlay module.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using any service to get data from server? As i can't see any service added in your app module. Please check that could be a issue.

Comment: I am using sigin.service.ts and doing @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})  https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24465 see this link i have explained in detail

Comment: I know that. I thought that could be and issue.. Thanks